# Questions about Samsung Galaxy Tab

Tags: 2.2-froyo, usb, vpn, samsung-galaxy-tab

I'm going to buy a Galaxy Tab and I'm hoping to find the answers here:

1. Can I plug in a USB flash memory or an external hard-disk to Galaxy Tab via any USB Converter?
2. Does Android 2.2 support VPN connections?
3. Are Android applications free?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 - No. There is a microSD slot where you can insert cards upto 32 GB in size to extend the memory.

2 - Yes - VPN support is present in 2.1 as well

3 - Some are free, some are not. Some are ad-supported.

Comment: Thank you very much, So there is no trick to connect a usb flash memory, like the way iPad does ? http://www.macstories.net/ipad/connecting-a-usb-flash-drive-to-the-ipad/

Comment: I mean can i use something like this with its usb cable to connect a flash memory to it? : http://www.aliexpress.com/product-gs/361666970-USB-A-Male-to-USB-A-Female-Adapter-Converter-wholesalers.html

Comment: @Saba Jamalian: Android does not yet support USB Host mode (USB OTG); however there are hacks on some hardware that allows it to become USB host http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3-bLOc1qnMM Given that Linux kernel already support USB OTG and that the upcoming Android 3.0 (Honeycomb) will be focusing on tablet, it is possible that USB Host may be supported.

Comment: My archos 70 suppots usb host. Are you sure the galaxy tab doesn't?

Comment: @Matt - Pretty sure...that's an area where Archos has the upper hand.